# Mysql: Create new field adding multiple substrings from another column

Tags: mysql, regex

**I need to create a new column, searching multiple substring from another column. 
see sample at the link below
[see sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuOFf.png)

i was able to look for multiple substrings but i wasn't able to enter the substrings i located, under the same new column

here my code. it doesn't allow me to add the substrings under the same column. it just created four  columns with the same name and  under each of these columns the substrings were entered

```
SELECT 
  column a, 
  substring(column a, locate('playtstation', campaign a), length('playtstation')) as column b,
 substring(column a, locate('vr', campaign a), length('vr')) as column b,
 substring(column a, locate('dualshock', campaign a), length('dualshock')) as column b,
 substring(column a, locate('final fantasy', campaign a), length('final fantasy')) as column b,

FROM myTable 
WHERE name LIKE '%playstation%' OR '%vr%' OR '%dualshock%'OR '%final fantasy%'
```

Comment: please show the sample data you're running this query against. And as well as just saying you were "unable to" do something, also tell us what the code did instead.

Comment: check the sample data and i edited what the code did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not very clear what you are trying to get and why but here is my guess of what you are trying to achieve:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5HxNgCTf8TmAV9JWzQyGDd/2

```
 SELECT 
      campaign a, 
      IF(LOCATE('playstation', campaign), 'playtstation',
         IF(locate('vr', campaign), 'vr',
            IF(locate('dualshock', campaign), 'dualshock',
               IF(locate('final fantasy', campaign), 'final fantasy', NULL)
            )
         )
      ) as b
    FROM mytable 
    WHERE campaign LIKE '%playstation%' 
          OR campaign LIKE '%vr%' 
          OR campaign LIKE '%dualshock%'
          OR campaign LIKE '%final fantasy%'
```

As you can see from my fiddle you can get the same result with `WHERE` clause like:

```
WHERE campaign LIKE 'campaign-sony%'
```

And one another trick if you are sure about `campaign` structure:

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(campaign, '-', -1) as b
```

And then you have pretty nice and easy to read and easy to understand query:

```
SELECT 
  campaign a, 
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(campaign, '-', -1) as b
FROM mytable 
WHERE campaign LIKE 'campaign-sony%'
```